# Compute OpenCV functions server side on image sent from Android

Tags: c++, android, image, image-processing, opencv

**--EDIT--**

I wasn't very well understood with the initial question, so allow me to rephrase.

I am working in an image processing application for Android.

Let's admit I will send an image from android to some server.

What I want to know is how to process this image with opencv  (c/c++) on the server and return the results to mobile.

Comment: I really think it'll be much easier to call some java method from the native code that will send images, handle responses and notify the native code about results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. 
That is a good suggestion, however it might be much costly in terms of processing time, which I can't really spare. Another problem is how to deliver the image to the opencv c/c++ code and returning the results. Solutions using PHP and some extensions seem to me really time expansive. Are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: I don't understand exactly want you want to do. Do you want to process the image on the device using NDK and OpenCV or what?

Comment: I want to process the image using OpenCV on the server and send results back to the device

Comment: If your question is about Android, you don't need NDK for that. Use Java for sending and receiving the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into setting up a web service if you're just trying to offload the processing to a server and send back some processed data. There's a ton of examples and sample setups based on the server environment (OS, speed, bandwidth needs, etc) out there that should help you get started. You would then setup the OpenCV environment on the server, and perform all of your processing through those libraries. We would need more information on what type of image processing you hope to accomplish to help you more, but again there are lots of examples for OpenCV and great documentation as well. The Android side will depend on how you setup the web service, so based on that choice there are different solutions available for easily interfacing with your server.

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept the answer if that was what you were looking for.

Comment: actually, I wanted to write some more stuff, but I messed up with the comment, I was saying that my problem is exactly how to setup the opencv environment server side... my problem is not opencv, but how to put it to run and connect the phone to it and vice versa. you mentioned there are tons of examples on how to do that, perhaps you could name a few, only to get started. 
Thanks

Comment: I can try, I've never done exactly what you're doing, but here's my general approach: 1. Setup a web service on the server using your framework of choice. Since you talk about C/C++, look into a C++ platform that uses JSON, REST, or SOAP protocols for easier comm. 2. Install OpenCV on the server, and make a test app to make sure it works as expected without the web service. 3. Create classes/methods to combine the two using framework. 4. Setup Android app to test comm with server. I would use HttpClient and HttpPost (since you need to send image), along with UrlEncodedFormEntity.